# Background Check JS

Tags: javascript, plugins

I have a question in regards to this [plug in](http://kennethcachia.com/background-check), hopefully someone can help me out

I have a background image that is set via JavaScript after a particular page has loaded. The background can at any point be a light or dark image, loaded by the user. The plug in works well when the images are known at run time (as in the -css and -fullscreen demos), but fails to allow developers to check whether the background is embedded in the body.

I tried modifying the plugin to fit my needs but every attempt thus far breaks the plugin.

Is is possible to retrieve the image data from a dynamically assigned background image after it has been set by JS?

Loading the base64 image into a `<canvas />` is not working for me either as the image should, but does not get rendered (img.onload never gets fired) after appending it as a child to the current document instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="background-check.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css"/>
      <style type="text/css">.fixed {left: 0;position: absolute;top: 0;width: 50%;}.fixed-nav {position: absolute;left: 50%;top: 47px;width: 280px;margin-left: -140px;text-align: center;}.fixed-nav.background--dark .fixed-nav-line {background: #fff;}.fixed-nav.background--dark .fixed-nav-logo {color: #fff;}.fixed-nav.background--dark .fixed-nav-no {color: #fff;}.fixed-nav.background--dark .fixed-nav-name {color: #fff;}.fixed-nav-line,.fixed-nav-logo {display: inline-block;vertical-align: middle;margin: 0;padding: 0;}.fixed-nav-line {width: 40px;height: 3px;background: #222;}.fixed-nav-logo {height: 28px;font-size: 25px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;}</style>
      <script type="text/javascript"> /* global BackgroundCheck:false */window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {BackgroundCheck.init({targets: '.fixed-nav'});});function readURL(input) {if (input.files && input.files[0]) { var reader = new FileReader(); reader.onload = function(e) { $('#previewHolder').attr('src', e.target.result); //alert(e.target.result); } reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);}}window.onload = function(){$('#previewHolder').attr('src','Winter.jpg');$("#filePhoto").change(function() { readURL(this);});}</script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="fixed">
         <div class="fixed-nav">
            <div class="fixed-nav-logo">22&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;22&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;22&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;222</div>
            <div class="fixed-nav-name">ssssss</div>
            <div class="fixed-nav-no">ssssssss</div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <input type="file" name="filePhoto" value="" id="filePhoto" class="required borrowerImageFile" data-errormsg="PhotoUploadErrorMsg"><img id="previewHolder" alt="Uploaded Image Preview Holder" width="400px" height="200px"/>
   </body>
</html>
```